# xml + xslt conversion from .txt in php 

Tags: php, xml

I have few files in .txt format (these files are either saved in a folder or opened from the desktop after execution).

I would like to build an application in PHP that allow to retrieve these files and save them in a XML format and then display then dynamically with XSLT.

is there any methods that allow me to do this?

Thank you

Comment: This is a English website. Please, translate your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is *very vague*!

You need to:

1. open the files
2. parse them however you need to some data structure
3. construct the XML using [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), [`XMLWriter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php), [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or some third-party library
4. write an XSLT file to process the XML into your desired output
5. apply the XSLT transform using [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [`XSLTProcessor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)
6. save or echo the output

Comment: thnks but to open the files and parse it i do many codes but any result...can you help me more ...

Comment: No, I literally cannot, because you have told us nothing specific about your problem. Even if I wanted to do everything for you, I would be unable to because your question is too vague. If you have a specific problem with a specific piece of code (such as your txt parser), post a new question with your input, code, desired output and actual output and we will try and help

Comment: i try many methode to open and parse files but i havn't any result ....plz ia can't do any things in this application and i haven't more times can you give me pmore details ...can you contact me by mail foufaskt@gmail.com ..and thnks a lot